# How to read a sentence of char pointer with scanf()?

Tags: c, string, pointers, scanf, char-pointer

I have a char pointer: `char *sentences;` and I read it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *sentences;
    sentences="We test coders. Give us a try?";
    printf("%s", sentences);
    return 0;
}
```

but I want to read with `scanf()` function in c.

`scanf("%[^\n]s",S);` or `scanf("%s",S);` didn't work.

How can I do that?

Comment: The `gets` function is dangerous, and should never be used. Modern C standards no longer support it. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you declaring the variable `char *sentences;` and immediately trying to write to it with `scanf`? That's not going to work.

Unless a `char *` pointer is pointing to an existing string, or to memory allocated with `malloc`-family functions, assigning to it with `scanf` or similar is undefined behavior:

```
char *sentences;
scanf("%s", sentences); // sentences is a dangling pointer - UB
```

Since you haven't actually shared your code that uses `scanf` and doesn't work, I can only assume that's the problem.

If you want to assign a user-supplied value to a string, what you can do is declare it as an array of fixed length and then read it with a suitable input function. `scanf` will work if used correctly, but `fgets` is simpler:

```
char sentence[200];
fgets(sentence, 200, stdin);
// (User inputs "We test coders. Give us a try")

printf("%s", sentence);
// Output: We test coders. Give us a try.
```

Also, never, ever use `gets`.

Comment: Suggest `printf("<%s>\n", sentence);` so OP will see that the `'\n'` is retained.

Comment: @M.M Right. Updated my ansewr